# Can I add more RAM to the stm32f103c8t6?

Tags: stm32, embedded, arm, camera

I am currently working on my project using the "super blue pill" which uses the stm32f103c8t6. This board has about 20kb of RAM so there is not too much to work with here.

[image]So far I have managed to hook up my Bluetooth module, small OLED display and now am trying to get my camera functioning, here is the thing I need help with - because this board has 20kb of ram I don't think I can hold this in memory even if the JPG is compressed.

Two options:
  - 1) Get another chip one that has 1 MB or ram preferably.
  - 2) the cheaper option use external ram or find another creative way to preserve the image and ship it off to the bluetooth to send to the users phone ( perhaps write to a SD card)

How I might do this on [this board](https://medium.com/swlh/super-blue-pill-like-stm32-blue-pill-but-better-6d341d9347da) and preferably what ram ID# I should use and the best supplier. I also am curious if I could somehow write to a SD then read and send the image off? Although I think the external ram is more efficient and quicker - but i'm just a newbie so not too sure!

Here is some numbers and points for consideration

VGA - 640 x 480 x 3 = 921.6KB

- Does the camera have compression and can mitigate memory footprint?
- Image cannot be in grayscale! This will go to a Django backend for image processing

UPDATED REQUIREMENTS:

- drive some kind of display
- able to take a photo and send it to the users phone quality standards
  need to be 640 x 480 or better

Biggest thing here is the camera. This circuit is being used to take a photo of object(s) then is being sent to a backend for p reprocessing and finally ran through a predictive model.

Comment: Generally speaking MCUs are not what you want to use to work with a camera.  While there are single-chip flash based MCU's with 100-200 KB of RAM they tend to get more expensive, to the point where small SoC modules designed to use external memories may be cheaper, and have the connectivity which your present solution lacks anyway.  It may be time to re-evaluate your whole approach.

Comment: Is there any particular discovery board you potentially have in mind that could be recommended for a project like this?

Comment: No, because you have not defined your requirements.  Maybe you should use a pi zero temporarily until you have fully defined the task, then find something lower power and more reliable to run it on once you know the exact need.

Comment: Get an F7/H7 board. Or *at least* an external memory interface. (FSMC) An F4 can work as well, but probably not in color.

Comment: There is also the PIC32MZ DA family. Some have 32MB of in-package DRAM (afaik another die bonded on top of the actual processor in the same package). They also come in convenient-ish 176-pin LQFP packages if BGAs are too much of a hassle. They're not terribly cheap however, at ~$11 apiece in quantity.

Comment: Please see updated requirements

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can add more ram, but it won't be quicker as you will only be able to add ram with a serial interface which is slow (because the data and address bytes are sent serially). The STM32f1's don't have parallel hardware interface (FMSC), I am not sure the F3's do but some of the F4's do and F7's and H7's series.  It's better to find a dev board with an fmsc ram built in because wiring up an external ram (40+ wires, and keeping capacitance low) is probably pushing the limits of the most experienced prototyper.

You might be able to find an F4 in the same package size with more ram since many of ST's product lines have pin compatibility and replace the 103 on your dev board.